# Converting numbers to words in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, numbers-to-words

Here's a program I wrote to convert numbers into English words using Haskell.

```
import Data.Char
import Data.List

type WordNum = String

ones :: (Integral a, Show a) => a -> WordNum
ones 1 = "one"
ones 2 = "two"
ones 3 = "three"
ones 4 = "four"
ones 5 = "five"
ones 6 = "six"
ones 7 = "seven"
ones 8 = "eight"
ones 9 = "nine"
ones n = error (show n ++ " is not a one-digit value")

teens :: (Integral a, Show a) => a -> WordNum
teens 10 = "ten"
teens 11 = "eleven"
teens 12 = "twelve"
teens 13 = "thirteen"
teens 14 = "fourteen"
teens 15 = "fifteen"
teens 16 = "sixteen"
teens 17 = "seventeen"
teens 18 = "eighteen"
teens 19 = "nineteen"
teens n  = error (show n ++ " is not a teen")

tens :: (Integral a, Show a) => a -> WordNum
tens 1 = "ten"
tens 2 = "twenty"
tens 3 = "thirty"
tens 4 = "forty"
tens 5 = "fifty"
tens 6 = "sixty"
tens 7 = "seventy"
tens 8 = "eighty"
tens 9 = "ninety"
tens n  = error (show n ++ " is not a tens place value")

groups :: [WordNum]
groups = ["", " thousand", " million", " billion", " trillion"]


groupToWord :: (Integral a, Show a) => a -> String
groupToWord n
    | n == 0    = ""
    | n < 10    = ones n
    | n < 20    = teens n
    | n < 100   = tens (n `div` 10) ++ ' ' : (groupToWord $ n `mod` 10)
    | n < 1000  = ones (n `div` 100) ++ " hundred " ++ (groupToWord $ n `mod` 100)
    | otherwise = error (show n ++ " is not a 3-digit group")

-- Splits a number into groups in reverse order
splitNum :: (Integral a, Show a) => a -> [a]
splitNum n
    | n <= 999  = [n]
    | otherwise = (n `mod` 1000) : splitNum (n `div` 1000)

numToWord :: (Integral a, Show a) => a -> String
numToWord n
    | n == 0     = "zero"
    | n >= 10^15 = error "Doesn't support numbers bigger than trillions"
    | otherwise  = concat $ intersperse ", " [w ++ g | (w,g) <- reverse (zip wordGroups groups)]
    where
        wordGroups = toWordGroups $ splitNum n

        toWordGroups :: (Integral a, Show a) => [a] -> [WordNum]
        toWordGroups (g:gs) = groupToWord g : toWordGroups gs
        toWordGroups _ = []
```

It seems like there's a lot of redundancy, and I'm also not very happy with how I had to join the lists. Also, is there a way to do more consing and less appending? I was hoping to cons the groups back together after they were made words so I wouldn't have to reverse the zipped list afterward. Also, as always, I'd really appreciate general comments on improvements to style and best practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Pattern matching or list element selection?

It's possible to reduce the size of `ones`, `tens`, `teens` and so on if we use `!!` on a list instead of pattern matching. That's a completely other style though:

```
ones :: (Integral a, Ord a) => a -> WordNum
ones n 
  | n > 0 && n < 10 = onsies !! fromIntegral n
  | otherwise       = error $ "ones: not a one-digit value"
  where
    onsies = words "one two three four five six seven eight nine"
```

Note that I removed the `Show a` constraint, because it's not necessary if our value `n` is in our range. It's only necessary in the `error` case. Instead, we should add *where* the error happened. Newer variants of GHC/base include a call-stack, therefore we will know the malfunctioning line, but it's always nice to know at least the function name. It also follows the `base`-style error messages, e.g.

```
head (x:_) = x
head []    = error "Prelude.head: empty list"
```

Either way, back to the code. Several functions are partial. Usually, you want your *exported* functions to be total, e.g. they never return `_|_` (an infinite loop, an error, `undefined`,...). So instead of the `ones` above, we could write

```
ones :: (Integral a, Ord a) => a -> Maybe WordNum
ones n 
  | n > 0 && n < 10 = Just $ onsies !! fromIntegral n
  | otherwise       = Nothing
  where
    onsies = words "one two three four five six seven eight nine"
```

However you wouldn't export all your helper functions either way, so lets keep the `error` variant. By the way, I've used `words "one..."` since my keyboard is slightly broken, but it's the same as `["one","two","three",...]`.

## `divMod`, `map` and other standard library functions

Sometimes re-inventing the wheel is fun, but usually we want to try to get the most out of our standard library functions.

### `divMod`

There are several occasions where we use both `` d = a `div` b `` and `` m = a `mod` b ``. If we use both, we can use `` (d,m) = a `divMod` b ``. That prevents typos like

```
    | n < 100   = tens (n `div` 10) ++ ' ' : (groupToWord $ n `mod` 11)
                                                    -- whoops        ^
```

So let us use it in `splitNum`:

```
splitNum :: Integral a => a -> [a]
splitNum n
    | d == 0    = [n]
    | otherwise = m : splitNum d
  where
    (d,m) = n `divMod` 1000
```

Note that `quotRem` will return the same values as `divMod` *on positive numbers* and is slightly faster.

### `zipWith` and `map`

You use `zip` in your list comprehension just to `++` the zipped elements together. We can achieve this in a single step with `zipWith`:

```
[w ++ g | (w,g) <- reverse (zip wordGroups groups)]
= [ w ++ g | (w,g) <- reverse (zipWith (,)  wordGroups groups)]
= [ x      | x     <- reverse (zipWith (++) wordGroups groups)]
= reverse $ zipWith (++) wordGroups groups
```

`toWordGroups` is `map groupToWord`. If we use both functions in `numToWord`, we end up with

```
numToWord :: (Integral a, Ord a) => a -> String
numToWord n
    | n == 0     = "zero"
    | n >= 10^15 = error "numToWord: Doesn't support numbers bigger than trillions"
    | otherwise  = concat $ intersperse ", " $ reverse $ zipWith (++) wordGroups groups
    where
        wordGroups = map groupToWord $ splitNum n
```