# Converting English words to numbers in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, numbers-to-words

A few weeks ago, I finished a [number to word converter](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/179402/85243) and received an excellent review. It caused me to make several fundamental changes to `numToWord`, such as using a list instead of a pattern matched function, using `quotRem`, and removing `Show` constraints. I also tried to use `zipWith`, but I wasn't sure how to make it work correctly when filtering before uncurrying. However, I'm more interested in improving my newer `wordToNum` converter. I played a little bit with trying to use `Maybe` and `Nothing` instead of defaulting to 0 everywhere, but it got very ugly very fast. Would there be a clean way of using Maybe throughout the module, and would it be better than defaulting to 0? Also, is there a cleaner way of splitting groups and blocks?

```
module MathSolver.NLP.WordNum (numToWord, wordToNum) where

import Data.Bool (bool)
import Data.Char
import Data.List.Split.Internals
import Data.Maybe

ones :: Integral a => [(String, a)]
ones = [("one",1), ("two",2), ("three",3), ("four",4), ("five",5), ("six",6), ("seven",7),
        ("eight",8), ("nine",9)]

teens :: Integral a => [(String, a)]
teens = [("ten",10), ("eleven",11), ("twelve",12), ("thirteen",13), ("fourteen",14),
         ("fifteen",15), ("sixteen",16), ("seventeen",17), ("eighteen",18), ("nineteen",19)]

tens :: Integral a => [(String, a)]
tens = [("ten",10), ("twenty",20), ("thirty",30), ("forty",40), ("fifty",50), ("sixty",60),
        ("seventy",70), ("eighty",80), ("ninety",90)]

groups :: [String]
groups = ["", " thousand", " million", " billion", " trillion", " quadrillion", " quintillion",
          " sextillion", " septillion", " octillion", " nonillion", " decillion", " undecillion",
          " duodecillion", " tredecillion", " quattuordecillion", " quindecillion", " sexdecillion",
          " septendecillion", " octodecillion", " novemdecillion", " vigintillion"]

-- Maps a word to its power of 10 to calculate a group multiplier
groupList :: Integral a => [(String, a)]
groupList = [("thousand",3), ("million",6), ("billion",9), ("trillion",12), ("quadrillion",15),
             ("quintillion",18), ("sextillion",21), ("septillion",24), ("octillion",27),
             ("nonillion",30), ("decillion",33), ("undecillion",36), ("duodecillion",39),
             ("tredecillion",42), ("quattuordecillion",45), ("quindecillion",48),
             ("sexdecillion",51), ("septendecillion",54), ("octodecillion",57),
             ("novemdecillion",60), ("vigintillion",63)]

{--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
{---                                   NUMBER TO WORD CONVERSION                                ---}
{--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------}

-- Converts an Int or Integer to its String representation
numToWord :: Integral a => a -> String
numToWord n
    | n < 0      = "negative " ++ numToWord (-n)
    | n == 0     = "zero"
    | n >= 10^65 = error "numToWord: Doesn't support numbers bigger than vigintillions! (10^65-1)"
    | isHundred  = groupToWord d100 ++ " hundred"
    | otherwise  = unwords $ reverse buildGroups
    where
        buildGroups = map (uncurry (++)) (filter (\(block,_) -> block /= "") (zip wordGroups groups))
        wordGroups = map groupToWord $ splitNum n

        isHundred = n <= 9000 && r1000 /= 0 && r100 == 0
        r1000 = n `rem` 1000
        (d100,r100) = n `quotRem` 100

-- Splits a number into groups in reverse order
splitNum :: Integral a => a -> [a]
splitNum n
    | d == 0  = [n]
    | otherwise = m : splitNum d
    where
        (d,m) = n `quotRem` 1000

-- Converts a group of digits to a number.
-- A group is usually 1 to 3 digits, but also includes numbers that are multiples of 100, but not
-- 1000, such as 1900. Words are not comma-separated as per the Chicago Manual of Style. This
-- prevents numbers from potentially seeming like a list of smaller numbers.
groupToWord :: Integral a => a -> String
groupToWord n = unwords $ numWords n
  where
    numWords :: Integral a => a -> [String]
    numWords r
        | r < 0                = "negative" : numWords (-r)
        | r == 0               = []
        | r < 10               = [toWord r ones]
        | r < 20               = [toWord r teens]
        | r < 100 && r10 /= 0  = [toWord n10 tens ++ "-" ++ toWord r10 ones]
        | r < 100              = toWord n10 tens : numWords r10
        | r < 1000             = toWord d100 ones : "hundred" : numWords r100
        | otherwise            = error "groupToWord: not a 3-digit or hundred group"
        where
            (n10, r10) = (r - r10, r `rem` 10)
            (d100, r100) = r `quotRem` 100

-- Converts a number to a word given a number translation map
toWord :: Integral a => a -> [(String, a)] -> String
toWord n table = fromMaybe "" (lookup n (map swap table))
  where
    swap :: Integral a => (String, a) -> (a, String)
    swap (x,y) = (y,x)

{--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
{---                                   WORD TO NUMBER CONVERSION                                ---}
{--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------}

-- Converts a single block to an Int or Integer
wordToNum :: Integral a => String -> a
wordToNum s
    | s == ""     = 0
    | isNegative  = (-1) * wordToNum (unwords $ tail (words s))
    | otherwise   = fromGroups $ splitGroups s
    where
        isNegative = head (words s) `elem` ["negative", "minus"]

-- Splits a full number into blocks on group words, keeping delimeters at the end of each group.
splitGroups :: String -> [String]
splitGroups str = map unwords $ split (dropBlanks $ oneOf groupWords) (words str)
  where
    -- Removes initial space in each entry of `groups` and ignores initial ""
    groupWords = map tail (tail groups)

-- Calculates the total sum of all groups' values
fromGroups :: Integral a => [String] -> a
fromGroups (block:group:bs) = fromBlock (splitBlock block) * (multiplier group) + fromGroups bs
fromGroups [block] = fromBlock (splitBlock block)
fromGroups [] = 0

-- Calculates a group's multiplier, or defaults to 1 (10^0) if the group isn't valid
multiplier :: Integral a => String -> a
multiplier g = 10 ^ fromMaybe 0 (lookup g groupList)

-- Splits a block on "hundred", keeping the delimeter, and cleaning spacing and punctuation
splitBlock :: String -> [String]
splitBlock block = map clean $ split (onSublist "hundred") block
  where
    -- Switches all hyphens to spaces and removes all other non-letters
    clean :: String -> String
    clean w = [bool ' ' c (c /= '-') | c <- (unwords.words) w, isLetter c || c == '-' || c == ' ']

-- Calculates a block's value, defaulting to 0 if there's invalid input
fromBlock :: Integral a => [String] -> a
fromBlock [x,"hundred",y] = fromBlock (words x) * 100 + fromBlock (words y)
fromBlock [x,"hundred"] = fromBlock (words x) * 100
fromBlock [x,y]
    | mapMember x (tail tens) && mapMember y ones  = fromWord x tens + fromWord y ones
    | otherwise                                    = 0
fromBlock [w]
    | length (words w) > 1   = fromBlock (words w)
    | mapMember w ones       = fromWord w ones
    | mapMember w teens      = fromWord w teens
    | mapMember w tens       = fromWord w tens
    | otherwise              = 0
fromBlock _ = 0

-- Converts a word to its numeric value from a given conversion table
fromWord :: Integral a => String -> [(String, a)] -> a
fromWord word table = fromMaybe 0 (lookup word table)

-- Determines whether a word is a member of a conversion table
mapMember :: Integral a => String -> [(String, a)] -> Bool
mapMember w table = isJust (lookup w table)
```

**Edit**: For `groupWords` in `splitGroups`, would it be better to use `map (\(group,_) -> group) groupList`? Similarly, would it be better to replace `groups` entirely with `"" : map (\(group,_) -> " " ++ group) groupList`?